# Php+mysql, Chinese characters is garbled when using "join"

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have both English and Chinese Character in my database.My code is like:

```
mysql_select_db($database,$con); 
mysql_query("set character set 'utf8'");
$result=mysql_query($sqlStatement);
```

When I select from only one table, Chinese character can returned normally and correctly.

However,when the sql statement is like

```
select TableA.a from TableA join TableB on TableA.b=TableB.b
```

the Chinese Character does not work. Result is "?". It seems like each Chinese character corresponds to two "?".

My database:

```
character_set_client gdk
character_set_connection gdk
character_set_database gdk
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_result gdk
character_set_server gdk
character_set_system utf8
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Are the tables in UTF-8 ?

Comment: No, only character_set_system is utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Check the field's collation are utf8_general_ci.(For example, set utf8_general_ci for your database).
2. Check the meta tag inside  section in html:

May be this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into the table, try using:

```
$Var = html_specialchars($_POST['Input_1']);
```

Tell me if it works :)